# Performing redirection with react-router

Tags: react-router

I want to make it so that when an AJAX request comes back with an unauthorized response the user is sent to an unauthorized page, something like this:

```
xhr.get(url)
    then(
        data => ...,
        err => {
            if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
                //perform redirect
            }
        }
    );
```

I know that you can use the `Navigation` mixin (although that'll be [removed shortly](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/835)) but how would you make it a global error handler, not tied to a particular component?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the social-search-hybrid-client project on github.

[Router.jsx](https://github.com/michalradziwon/social-search-hybrid-client/blob/master/src/app/Router.jsx) exposes #transitionTo() function that delegates the method call to the router. That allows you to *require* Router.jsx in any part of the app stores/actions/views.

For usage example see [Security.js](https://github.com/michalradziwon/social-search-hybrid-client/blob/e820d4e7b2f46f3f532657ffac57d18839a3f049/src/app/Security.js)